# authentication error in Cloud Datalab: "ImportError: No module named gce”

Tags: google-oauth, google-cloud-datalab

The following problem has been encountered by me and others in a variety of different GCP projects, and under circumstances where the same code worked a few days earlier.

I am walking through all of the steps again right now, just to make sure that I still see the same thing.  I started by deleting the running instance of Cloud Datalab in my GCP project, and then I started over: first deploy Datalab, then "start using" Datalab.

I then select a pre-existing notebook that I have which starts with the following lines:

```
!pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
http = Http()
credentials.authorize(http)
```

This has worked in the past for me and for others.  Now I get this ImportError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-deffc94100d1> in <module>()
      1 from httplib2 import Http
      2 from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
----> 3 credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
      4 http = Http()
      5 credentials.authorize(http)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.pyc in get_application_default()
   1202         GoogleCredentials.get_application_default().
   1203   
-> 1204         Args:
   1205             access_token: string, access token.
   1206             client_id: string, client identifier.

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.pyc in _get_implicit_credentials(cls)
   1187     """
   1188 
-> 1189     NON_SERIALIZED_MEMBERS =  (
   1190         frozenset(['_private_key']) |
   1191         OAuth2Credentials.NON_SERIALIZED_MEMBERS)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.pyc in _implicit_credentials_from_gce()
   1123 
   1124 def _in_gae_environment():
-> 1125     """Detects if the code is running in the App Engine environment.
   1126 
   1127     Returns:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.pyc in _get_application_default_credential_GCE()
   1378         """Get the Application Default Credentials for the current environment.
   1379 
-> 1380         Raises:
   1381             ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError: raised when the credentials
   1382                                                 fail to be retrieved.

ImportError: No module named gce
```

Has something changed?  has a module that was previously named "gce" been renamed?  do I need to create credentials?  (The project has both a default App Engine service account and a default Compute Engine service account, and has all of the APIs that I think might need to be enabled already enabled.)

20-apr-2016 UPDATE: After not trying to repeat this for about a month, I was looking at this again yesterday.  The first time I tried to re-run the same notebook I was working with last month, I needed to take *out* the fix I had added in as a result of this issue in order to get it to work.  But today that same code would again not work.  In the mean-time I noticed that the recommendations had been updated, so I am now going to walk through the recommended approaches.

```
!pip show google-api-python-client
---
Name: google-api-python-client
Version: 1.5.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: httplib2, uritemplate, six, oauth2client
```

Looking [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/setup.py)  the specific versions required seem to be: httplib2>=0.8,<1; *any* oauth2client; six>=1.6.1,<2; and uritemplate>=0.6,<1.  (The change to allow earlier oauth2client versions seems to have been committed on Mar 14, but [Pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-api-python-client/) shows the most recent version as 1.5.0 uploaded on Feb 20, which agrees with the [Releases page](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/releases) which says that 1.5.0 was released on Feb 19, which may have been when this problem originally appeared although I didn't notice it for a few weeks.)

I have not been able to get much further in trying out the 3 options described by Anthonios because I repeatedly get "Connection failed" or other errors when trying to use Datalab.  I will try to update this issue again soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may install additional python libraries in Datalab, but you must make sure that the installation does not break the working Datalab environment. The best way to ensure this is by checking to see whether the dependencies required by the additional python library are currently installed in Datalab. Follow the steps below:

**Step 1: Confirm which dependencies are required for the library that you want to install**

Use `!pip show <python library>`
For example, use the following to view dependencies required for `google-api-python-client` :

```
>>> !pip show google-api-python-client
---
Name: google-api-python-client
Version: 1.5.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: httplib2, uritemplate, six, oauth2client
```

The specific versions required can be found [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/setup.py).

**Step 2: Determine whether any of the dependencies are already installed in Datalab**

In Datalab, run the following code and check for the dependencies in step 1

```
>>> import pip
>>> for dist in pip.get_installed_distributions():
>>>   print dist
GCPData 0.1.0
GCPDataLab 0.1.0
wheel 0.26.0
tensorflow 0.6.0
protobuf 3.0.0a3
nbformat 4.0.1
ipykernel 4.2.2
jsonschema 2.5.1
nose 1.3.7
singledispatch 3.4.0.3
pyparsing 2.0.7
pandas 0.17.1
futures 3.0.3
pyasn1-modules 0.0.8
mock 1.3.0
MarkupSafe 0.23
cycler 0.9.0
ipython 4.0.3
terminado 0.6
path.py 8.1.2
certifi 2015.11.20.1
Pygments 2.1
funcsigs 0.4
backports-abc 0.4
jupyter-client 4.1.1
pexpect 4.0.1
backports.ssl-match-hostname 3.5.0.1
statsmodels 0.6.1
seaborn 0.6.0
scikit-learn 0.16.1
rsa 3.3
jupyter-core 4.0.6
brewer2mpl 1.4.1
py-dateutil 2.2
patsy 0.4.1
ptyprocess 0.5
PyYAML 3.11
Jinja2 2.8
decorator 4.0.6
pandocfilters 1.2.4
pickleshare 0.6
sympy 0.7.6
pytz 2015.7
httplib2 0.9.2
functools32 3.2.3-2
notebook 4.0.2
tornado 4.3
simplegeneric 0.8.1
numpy 1.10.4
matplotlib 1.5.1
scipy 0.17.0
pyasn1 0.1.9
pbr 1.8.1
python-dateutil 2.4.2
traitlets 4.1.0
oauth2client 1.4.12
ipython-genutils 0.1.0
nbconvert 4.1.0
ggplot 0.6.5
mistune 0.7.1
```

Based on the output in this example, one conflict is that Datalab currently has `oauth2client` version `1.4.12` installed, and the `google-api-python-client` library requires a version of `oauth2client` that is greater than or equal to `2.0.0` .

We have 3 options :

- Wait until Datalab upgrades support for `oauth2client` to `>=2.0.0`
- Install a prior version of `google-api-python-client` that supports the existing installation of `oauth2client` 1.4.12. For example, google-api-python-client [1.4.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-api-python-client/1.4.2)
- Try installing the latest `google-api-python-client` while maintaining the existing `oauth2client` installation. This can be achieved by installing `google-api-python-client` without dependencies, then manually installing any missing dependencies that are not already installed in Datalab. (There is a chance that the library may not work properly, but we are less likely to break the working Datalab environment). For example:

  `!pip install google-api-python-client==1.5.0 --no-deps`
  `!pip install uritemplate`

Comment: Thank you Anthonios.  The work around you provided does fix the problem in calling credentials.authorize().  However, the next two lines in my script result in another error which is described [here](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/issues/414).  What I am doing next is to ``from apiclient import discovery`` and then I use discovery.build() to build a genomics service.

Comment: Try using version 1.5.0 of google-api-python-client . If it fails, try replacing --force-reinstall with --ignore-installed to ensure the installation is not skipped

Comment: still no luck -- maybe I need to roll back to an earlier version of the google-api-python-client as well? (I have apiclient 1.5.0 and httplib2 0.9.2)  --  just to be clear, above when you said to try using 1.5.0 you were referring to the google-api-python-client not the oauth2client?

Comment: the latest error, btw, is in ``/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/gce.py`` and says: ``ImportError: cannot import name HttpAccessTokenRefreshError``

Comment: Yes. Try rolling back the google-api-python-client as well. I've updated my answer

Comment: What you are doing is not something we encourage. You need to be very careful about installing things in the container that have dependencies shared by Datalab itself, as you could break things. Right now Datalab is locked to oauthclient 1.5.2 so that is the right one to specify. Before adding anything check container/datalab/Dockerfile.in to see what versions of things Datalab is using.

Comment: Can you confirm that the current oauth2client version used by Datalab is `1.5.2`?


`>>import oauth2client`
`>>oauth2client.__version__`

`> 1.4.12`

Comment: @GrahamWheeler I've updated my answer. Please feel free to add further edits/comments to help improve the answer.