# Unable to Connect to Bigquery API from DataLab

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

I am running the following code in Python to connect to big query api from the data lab notebook:

```
!pip install google-api-python-client==1.4.2 httplib2==0.9.2 oauth2client==1.5.2 pyasn1==0.1.9 pyasn1-modules==0.0.8 rsa==3.2.3 simplejson==3.8.1 six==1.10.0 uritemplate==0.6 wheel==0.24.0

import httplib2
import time
import datetime as dt
import sys
import subprocess
from googleapiclient import errors
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
import gcp.bigquery as bq
import pandas as pd

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
```

I get the following error:

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
>     in ()
>
> ----> 5 credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
>   6 
>   7 bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.pyc in >get_application_default()
>      1202         """
>      1203         return self
>   -> 1204 
>      1205     @property
>      1206     def serialization_data(self):
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.pyc in  _get_implicit_credentials(cls)
>      1187             access_token, client_id, client_secret, refresh_token,
>      1188             token_expiry, token_uri, user_agent, revoke_uri=revoke_uri)
>   -> 1189 
>      1190     def create_scoped_required(self):
>      1191         """Whether this Credentials object is scopeless.
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.pyc in _implicit_credentials_from_gce()
>      1123 def _in_gce_environment():
>      1124     """Detect if the code is running in the Compute Engine environment.
>   -> 1125 
>      1126     Returns:
>      1127         True if running in the GCE environment, False otherwise.
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.pyc in _get_application_default_credential_GCE()
>      1378         credentials: the credentials to be saved to the well known file;
>      1379                      it should be an instance of GoogleCredentials
>   -> 1380         well_known_file: the name of the file where the credentials are to be
>      1381                          saved; this parameter is supposed to be used for
>      1382                          testing only
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/gce.py in ()
>        24 from oauth2client._helpers import _from_bytes
>        25 from oauth2client import util
>   ---> 26 from oauth2client.client import HttpAccessTokenRefreshError
>        27 from oauth2client.client import AssertionCredentials
>        28
>
> ImportError: cannot import name HttpAccessTokenRefreshError

What am I missing?  Why does this google provided example not work on data lab?

Comment: Why are you not just using the BigQuery support built into Datalab (in gcp.bigquery and in the supported %bigquery magics)?

Answer (score 1):

After doing some googling I found the answer here: [authentication error in Cloud Datalab: "ImportError: No module named gce”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142739/authentication-error-in-cloud-datalab-importerror-no-module-named-gce)

This solution solved my issue.

Comment: That other issue may solve your problem, but you shouldn't need to jump through those hoops just for BigQuery (what I was doing in that issue was necessary because I was trying to build/use a Genomics service).  You can find lots of datalab / bigquery examples on github, for example: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datalab/tree/master/content/datalab/tutorials/BigQuery